# Application of uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

why doesn't Heisenberg's uncertainty principle also work for macroscopic bodies which are in-turn made up of quantum-particles?

ps: if proof is provided it will be a lot more useful.

Comment: Heisenberg's uncertainty principle holds universally, but have you thought about how large for instance $\sigma_x$ is for a macroscopic object?

Comment: i think one can make a calculation for a particle of say  1 gm moving with a velocity 10 m/s .At any instant its  uncertainty in the measurement of position of the particle can be calculated using uncertainty relation of position and momentum ,then it can be seen that the position uncertainty is not meaningful  quantitatively.